# How do I output a element like "element:something" from XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do I do so? I want to output the "d:lots" element. Trying to output other elements that does not have the ":prefix" works... but not for those with that...
Here is the XML file I have:

```
<feed xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/">
<title type="text">CarParkSet</title>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice.svc/CarParkSet
</id>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="CarParkSet" href="CarParkSet"/>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(1)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Suntec City Lots: 1049</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(1)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>Suntec City</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">1049</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Suntec City Lots: 1049</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.117</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2935</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8572</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(2)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Marina Square Lots: 1153</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(2)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>Marina Square</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">1153</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Marina Square Lots: 1153</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.127</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2911</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8575</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(3)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: The Esplanade Lots: 650</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(3)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>The Esplanade</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">650</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: The Esplanade Lots: 650</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.133</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2898</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8551</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(4)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Millenia Singapore Lots: 424</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(4)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>Millenia Singapore</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">424</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Millenia Singapore Lots: 424</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.143</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2928</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8603</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(5)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Singapore Flyer Lots: 226</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(5)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>Singapore Flyer</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">226</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Singapore Flyer Lots: 226</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.15</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2894</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8632</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(6)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Orchard Point Lots: 190</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(6)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">6</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Orchard Point</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">190</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Orchard Point Lots: 190</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.16</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3013</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8405</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(7)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: The Heeren Lots: 106</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(7)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">7</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>The Heeren</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">106</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: The Heeren Lots: 106</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.17</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3026</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8375</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(8)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Plaza Singapura Lots: 494</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(8)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">8</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Plaza Singapura</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">494</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Plaza Singapura Lots: 494</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.177</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3006</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8456</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(9)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: The Cathay Lots: 69</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(9)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">9</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>The Cathay</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">69</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: The Cathay Lots: 69</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.27</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2996</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.847</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(10)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Mandarin Hotel Lots: 199</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(10)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">10</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Mandarin Hotel</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">199</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Mandarin Hotel Lots: 199</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.277</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3019</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8366</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(11)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Ngee Ann City Lots: 956</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(11)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Ngee Ann City</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">956</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Ngee Ann City Lots: 956</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.063</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3028</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8347</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(12)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Wisma Atria Lots: 259</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(12)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">12</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Wisma Atria</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">259</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Wisma Atria Lots: 259</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.073</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3037786</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8332679</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(13)
</id>
<title type="text">Harbfront</title>
<summary type="text">Development: VivoCity P3 Lots: 1127</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(13)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Harbfront</d:Area>
<d:Development>VivoCity P3</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">1127</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: VivoCity P3 Lots: 1127</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.08</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2644</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8228</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(14)
</id>
<title type="text">Harbfront</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Sentosa Lots: 782</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(14)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">14</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Harbfront</d:Area>
<d:Development>Sentosa</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">782</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Sentosa Lots: 782</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.09</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2568</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8238</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(15)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Tang Plaza Lots: 226</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(15)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">15</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Tang Plaza</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">226</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Tang Plaza Lots: 226</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.1</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3046317</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8328278</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(16)
</id>
<title type="text">Harbfront</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Harbourfront Centre Lots: 198</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(16)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">16</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Harbfront</d:Area>
<d:Development>Harbourfront Centre</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">198</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Harbourfront Centre Lots: 198</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.107</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.264</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8203</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(17)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Far East Plaza Lots: 401</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(17)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">17</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Far East Plaza</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">401</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Far East Plaza Lots: 401</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.193</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3071</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8334</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(18)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Centrepoint Lots: 324</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(18)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">18</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Centrepoint</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">324</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Centrepoint Lots: 324</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.203</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3014</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8395</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(19)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Concorde Hotel Lots: 226</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(19)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">19</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Concorde Hotel</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">226</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Concorde Hotel Lots: 226</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.213</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3006</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8421</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(20)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: ION Orchard Lots: 403</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(20)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>ION Orchard</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">403</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: ION Orchard Lots: 403</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.23</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3043</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8319</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(21)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: 313@Somerset Lots: 189</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(21)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">21</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>313@Somerset</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">189</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: 313@Somerset Lots: 189</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.22</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.3012</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8384</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(22)
</id>
<title type="text">Harbfront</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Resorts World Sentosa Lots: 1358</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(22)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">22</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Harbfront</d:Area>
<d:Development>Resorts World Sentosa</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">1358</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Resorts World Sentosa Lots: 1358</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.233</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2568</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8238</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(23)
</id>
<title type="text">Harbfront</title>
<summary type="text">Development: VivoCity P2 Lots: 735</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(23)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">23</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Harbfront</d:Area>
<d:Development>VivoCity P2</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">735</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: VivoCity P2 Lots: 735</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.187</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.2644</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8228</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(24)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Orchard Central Lots: 265</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(24)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">24</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Orchard Central</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">265</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Orchard Central Lots: 265</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.243</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.300724</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.839945</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(25)
</id>
<title type="text">Orchard</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Park Mall Lots: 236</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(25)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">25</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Orchard</d:Area>
<d:Development>Park Mall</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">236</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Park Mall Lots: 236</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.253</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.297834</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.845268</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>
http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/CarParkSet(26)
</id>
<title type="text">Marina</title>
<summary type="text">Development: Marina Bay Sands Lots: 640</summary>
<updated>2012-03-15T02:21:56Z</updated>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="CarPark" href="CarParkSet(26)"/>
<category term="LTAModel.CarPark" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:CarParkID m:type="Edm.Int32">26</d:CarParkID>
<d:Area>Marina</d:Area>
<d:Development>Marina Bay Sands</d:Development>
<d:Lots m:type="Edm.Int32">640</d:Lots>
<d:Summary>Development: Marina Bay Sands Lots: 640</d:Summary>
<d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-03-15T02:19:32.26</d:CreateDate>
<d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.28414</d:Latitude>
<d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.859438</d:Longitude>
<d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some **tool** that will **help you**.

[Here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html) you have a good tutorial about **SimpleXML**, which is a famous tool to **manipulate XML** in **PHP**.

For your specific demand **look at** [Here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302). He **explain** a **solution** to your problem using **SimpleXML**. What you are looking for is : "*How to read XML Namespace*"

*Example get from the link to iterate all elements of your XML* :

```
 if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file("address.xml")) 
 { 
     echo "Unable to load XML file"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
     /*** loop over the elements ***/ 
     foreach( $xml as $element ) 
     { 
         print_r( $element ); 
     }
 }
```

I let you think about what to add to this example.

Comment: yes, and it works, but I do not know how to output "d:Distance"... do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

The `d:` is an alias for a namespace, often called namespace prefix. The actual internal element name of `d:lots` is `{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}:lots`.

Because this would be difficult to read, write and really large and annoying, XML uses aliases for the larger namespace strings.

```
<feed xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"...
```

To read XML with namespaces you define your own aliases and use Xpath expressions:

```
// create the dom, load the xml
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// create an xpath instance, register the namespace
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ds', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices');

// fetch the nodes, iterate them
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//ds:Lots') as $lot) {
  var_dump($lot->nodeValue);
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/158836